# SQL Server : using aggregations on partially null data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, powerapps

I am having an issue with some code that I'd like some help on. Attached below is a table that is coming into the SQL database from PowerApps:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+
|          ID           | ProductionOrder | Workstation |  Status   |    Date    | Pass | TotalTime |
+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+
| 60127429_1000_1_S035  |          108100 | S035        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |       121 |
| 60128523_1000_1_S120  |          884171 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        18 |
| 60128523_13000_1_S080 |          884172 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        26 |
| 60128523_13000_1_S090 |          884172 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        19 |
| 60128523_13000_1_S120 |          884172 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        16 |
| 60128523_28000_1_S070 |          884173 | S070        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        10 |
| 60128523_28000_1_S080 |          884173 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        16 |
| 60128523_28000_1_S090 |          884173 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        21 |
| 60128523_28000_1_S120 |          884173 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        17 |
| 60128523_47000_1_S080 |          884174 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        10 |
| 60128523_47000_1_S090 |          884174 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        50 |
| 60128523_47000_1_S120 |          884174 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        19 |
| 60128569_6000_1_S080  |          884698 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |         9 |
| 60128569_6000_1_S090  |          884698 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        47 |
| 60128569_6000_1_S120  |          884698 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        54 |
| 60129071_1000_1_S070  |          105597 | S070        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |       137 |
| 60129071_1000_1_S080  |          105597 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        12 |
| 60129071_1000_1_S090  |          105597 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        21 |
| 60129071_23000_1_S070 |          105598 | S070        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        50 |
| 60129071_23000_1_S080 |          105598 | S080        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        12 |
| 60129071_23000_1_S090 |          105598 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        29 |
| 60129071_23000_1_S120 |          105598 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        20 |
| 60129071_23025_1_S020 |          105600 | S020        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | Yes  |        21 |
| 60129151_2000_1_S090  |          104974 | S090        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        26 |
| 60129151_2000_1_S120  |          104974 | S120        | Completed | 05/13/2020 | No   |        24 |
+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+
```

Next, I am creating a view to get some metrics by grouping each workstation. Here is that code:

```
with cteNow AS 
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN 60 * DATEPART(HOUR, GETUTCDATE()) + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE()) > 60 * 21
            THEN CONVERT(float,(16 - 7) * 60) --minutes in (4 PM - 7 AM) * 60 minutes/hour
        ELSE
            CONVERT(float,60 * DATEPART(HOUR, GETUTCDATE()) + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE()) - ((7 + 5) * 60))
        END as MinutesToday
        , CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()), 101) as TargetDate 
)
SELECT dbs.Workstation, 

100.0 - ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dbs.Pass = 'Yes' AND Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN dbs.Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0), 0) AS RFT

FROM [Booms DBS] AS dbs LEFT JOIN [Booms Delay Entry] AS del ON dbs.ID = del.ID INNER JOIN cteNow AS N ON N.TargetDate = dbs.[Date]
GROUP BY dbs.Workstation, MinutesToday
```

The point of this is to measure "Right First Time" for each station. Every time there is a "Yes" value in the `Pass` column, it is a hit to RFT. For example, if there is ten total builds in a given station and five of them have "Yes" in the `Pass` column, that is 50% RFT.

However, this is always giving me a result of '100' for the `RFT` column. I am adding all these `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` caveats because sometimes the `Pass` column can be null and during some days, there may not be any data at all especially in the mornings. I am assuming that is where the issue lies. Am I not calculating this correctly? I can't think of any other way to not error out or get divide-by-zero errors if I don't include those null checking functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The point of this is to measure "Right First Time" for each station. Every time there is a "Yes" value in the Pass column, it is a hit to RFT. For example, if there is ten total builds in a given station and five of them have "Yes" in the Pass column, that is 50% RFT.

It seems like you want conditional aggregation. I don't get the purpose of the date arithmetics in your existing query, but this would do what you described:

```
select 
    workstation, 
    avg(case when statys = 'Completed' and pass = 'Yes' then 1.0 else 0 end) rft_rate
from dbs.workstation
group by workstation
```

This gives you one record per `workstation`, with a numeric value between 0 and 1 that represents the rate of records that have value `'Yes'` in column `pass`.